# Error validating geometry collection / multipolygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, geometry

I have just updated a table of polygons with a query which returned:

```
UPDATE parcel SET wkb_geometry = ST_Multi(wkb_geometry)

UPDATE 399212

Query returned successfully in 25 secs.
```

Now, all of the rows should contain multipolygons.

However, when I try validating geometries with `ST_MakeValid`, it turns out that there are geometry collections in stead of multipolygons.  How can I fix this or remove the geometry collections?

```
UPDATE parcel
SET wkb_geometry = ST_MakeValid(wkb_geometry) 
WHERE ST_IsValid(wkb_geometry) = 'f'

ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
NOTICE:  Too few points in geometry component at or near point -121.78764087332523 37.700189714113364
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your make valid in a [ST_CollectionExtract](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html), so:

```
UPDATE parcel
SET wkb_geometry = ST_Collectionextract(ST_MakeValid(wkb_geometry), 3)
WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(wkb_geometry)
```